# Why when I nest a Stencil component inside a normal div with a display flex, the component is not showing, unless I set the :host to width: 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stenciljs

```
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <ifx-progress-bar value="50" show-label="true"></ifx-progress-bar>
</div>
```

test-wrapper has:

```
   .test-wrapper { 
      display: flex;
    }
```

Progress-bar has:

```
.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  //width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
```

With or without width: 100% on the .progress-bar, the component is not showing, unless I add:

```
:host { 
width: 100%
}
```

how come?

`Display:flex` on the `.progress-bar` should have a default `width` of `100%`, and therefore it should push the component wrapper (`host`) to be `width 100%` too, right? Why do I need to explicitly set it to `width 100%`? What is its default value?

Answer (score 0):

> Display:flex on the .progress-bar should have a default width of 100%

This is not true. The default `width` value for most elements is `auto` which means the element determines it's own size (according to it's own CSS properties and/or content). Width would therefore be determined by the element itself and the layout context. Setting the display property to `flex` does not affect the element's size. And putting an element inside a flexbox layout does not control the size of the element unless you use `justify-content: stretch` and let the element size be `auto`. Other flexbox related properties like `flex`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` can also affect size. All you need to do is use flexbox to stretch your component to 100%:

```
   .test-wrapper { 
      display: flex;
      justify-content: stretch;
   }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content.

Comment: You are talking about the inner formatting context, i.e. how the child elements of a `flex` container behave. I was talking about the outer formatting context, i.e. how a `flex` container behaves in relation to its siblings.

Comment: The point was that you were wrong about `display: flex` and 100% width.

Comment: Only partly, because my reasoning was correct. The width of a flex container is not by default 100%, but `auto`. When inside a `block`, `auto` is `100%`, but when inside another `flex`, the `flex-shrink` is set to `0`, which causes the `width` to shrink to `0` unless explicitly set otherwise.  `Width 100%` set on the `.progress-bar` should work, but because shadow DOM is enabled in Stencil components, the encapsulation prevents the `width: 100%` on the `.progress-bar` from pushing the container.

Comment: Either you have some misunderstandings about flexbox or your explanation isn't clear. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.